# How to train Document AI to get specific fields?

Tags: ocr, cloud-document-ai

I have approximately 6000 documents in pdf format, they have a different structure but inside they all contain the same date and code (With different structure I mean that the location of these values ​​changes in each document) I am working with Document IA that extracts all the information, but I would like to know if there is a possibility to only extract the fields that I need. Would Document IA workbench be the best option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean creating a custom document extractor? You can do this in Document AI, Visit this link for this [feature](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/workbench/build-custom-processor).

Tldr; you will have to do this on Document AI's workbench and train your own extractor(Uploading files and train the processor to extract data specified) For steps on this feature, I would suggest to visit this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/workbench/build-custom-processor#creating_and_using_a_custom_document_extractor) for the detailed steps on this.

Also please be noted that this feature is on the [Preview](https://cloud.google.com/products#product-launch-stages) stage at the moment.  Preview offerings are often publicly announced, but are not necessarily feature-complete, and no SLAs or technical support commitments are provided for these.